# How to download multiple files from a site selecting each option of a dropdown using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

I am trying to download multiple files from a site using Selenium in python using the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www10.goiania.go.gov.br/TransWeb/FuncionariosExportarPopUp.aspx?_=1590514086637')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('WebPatterns_wt12_block_wtMainContent_wtcboReferencia')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
selectYear = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("WebPatterns_wt12_block_wtMainContent_wtcboReferencia"))
link = driver.find_element_by_id('WebPatterns_wt12_block_wtMainContent_wtbtnGerar')
for option in all_options[:267]:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    selectYear.select_by_value(option)
    link.click()
    time.sleep(5000)
```

But i'm getting this error and i do not know how to solve it.

```
TypeError: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable
```

This is the first time that i am using selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download multiple files from the site https://www10.goiania.go.gov.br/TransWeb/FuncionariosExportarPopUp.aspx?_=1590514086637 using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) selecting each option from the **Referência** [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www10.goiania.go.gov.br/TransWeb/FuncionariosExportarPopUp.aspx?_=1590514086637")
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='WebPatterns_wt12_block_wtMainContent_wtcboReferencia']"))))
  for opt in select.options:
      opt.click()
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Gerar']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
for option in range(len(all_options[:267])):
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try assigning the list of elements for all_options to a list, for iteration to work.Then read the elements in for loop.

all_options = []