# Python selenium select from dropdown by text

Tags: selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, css-selectors, python-3.8

I have a web process that I am working through to automate. The HTML looks as following:

```
<td class="v-formlayout-contentcell">
<div class="v-select v-widget v-has-width" id="gwt-uid-46" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-45" style="width: 225px;">
 <select class="v-select-select" size="1" tabindex="0" style="width: 225px;">
 <option value="null"></option><option value="1">21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study</option><option value="2">21/24 Long Term Auction</option></select></div></td>
```

I always know what my options are from the dropdown list.

If I know what option needs to be selected, is there a way to select that based on text of option. In this example I want to select `21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study`.

I cant use `id = "gwt-uid-46"` as I fear that might easily change.

Edit:
I noticed in the the HTML that there is another class with name as `class="v-select-select"`. So, none of the answers posted so far work as the it finds that class instead of the one I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

```
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.Class_name,"v-select-select"))
select.select_by_visible_text("21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study")
or 
select.select_by_value("1")
```

Comment: I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: 21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study. The second option gives error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: I have updated my answer  try to add wait and  for second option i forgot to add double quotes

Comment: And also check if its in iframe or it needs click event before showing up all dropdown options

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<option>` with text as **21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) from the [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "select.v-select-select"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text("21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='v-select-select']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text("21/24 Long Term Auction Credit Study")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to download multiple files from a site selecting each option of a dropdown using Selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029058/how-to-download-multiple-files-from-a-site-selecting-each-option-of-a-dropdown-u/62031069#62031069)